# In Java, what type represents a function or lambda expression that takes 3 parameters?

Tags: java, c#, lambda, java-8

Java 8 has `Supplier<T>` for 0 parameter functions, `Function<T, R>` for 1 parameter functions, and `BiFunction<T, U, R>` for 2 parameter functions.

What type represents a function or lambda expression that takes 3 parameters like in

```
SomeType lambda = (int x, double y, String z) -> x; // what is SomeType?
```

In C#, `Func<T, TResult>` is overloaded for up to 16 parameters so we could write

```
Func<int, double, string, int> lambda = (int x, double y, string z) => x;
```

Does the Java standard libraries provide anything similar or do you have to write your own "TriFunction" interface to handle functions with 3 arguments?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to write your own functional interface. The JDK does not provide such an implementation.

Note that you can always compose something like a `TriFunction` with existing types

```
Function<Integer, Function<Double, Function<String, Integer>>> func =
  i -> d -> s -> i + d.intValue() + Integer.parseInt(s);//whatever random implementation
func.apply(42).apply(1.5).apply("1234");
```

Answer (score 3):

The JDK only goes up to BiFunctions but nothing prevents you from creating a TriFunction:

```
@FunctionalInterface public interface TriFunction<T1, T2, T3, R> {
  R apply(T1 v1, T2 v2, T3 v3);
}

TriFunction<Integer, Double, String, Integer> f = (i, d, s) -> i;
```

Alternatively, if you need NFunctions with N up to 8, you can use [jOOλ](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOL) which has [a `Function3` interface](http://www.jooq.org/products/jOO%CE%BB/javadoc/0.9.5/) (and up to Function8 as well as TupleN which can be useful).